# jacoco agent on wildfly - 0% on covered classes

Tags: java, selenium, integration-testing, wildfly, jacoco

I've attached a jacoco agent to a widlfly instance, in order to have code coverage for server side code, while running selenium tests.
The exec file is generated but when I import the file to Intellij, it shows 0% of coverage for every class.

I've this options when I start wildfly: `-javaagent:c:/dev/jacoco/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=c:/dev/jacoco.exec`

Is there anything missing?

The classes I want to cover are in a jar (maven dependency) placed inside the war against which I run the tests.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The problem may be related with the way you are executing both server and tests. Are you using maven or another automation tool for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting wildfly inside IntelliJ and running selenium tests also using IntelliJ (selenium server is being started externally from the normal bat script).